# Value not set in custom renderer, when using different native control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Basically I'm using the custom renderer implementation for a `DatePicker` from [jrgcubano](https://gist.github.com/jrgcubano/4fdd6ec776c6ddeacb4d518b0355dd77). Now I want to provide a custom renderer for UWP. Therefore I exchange the control on UWP and want to use a `CalendarDatePicker` instead.

Basically, the properties `Date` and `NullableDate` should be the same (except for the case that `NullableDate` is null). So there is a sync for this (which sometimes sets the properties too often, but that's another story). What I experience now is, that `Date` has always a wrong value. Most of the time it has the default value, which is the current day (or it has the value 01.01.0001). This value seems that it can't be changed, because in debug mode it still has the same value after changing to a new one. Because of the sync it also happens that `NullableDate` gets a wrong value after it had the correct value one time. To get the custom renderer working it was also necessary to subscribe to the `DateChanged` event.

Here is my current implementation, which shows a fully working project:

*MainPage.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestExtendedDatePicker.MainPage"
             xmlns:renderer="clr-namespace:TestExtendedDatePicker;assembly=TestExtendedDatePicker"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <StackLayout>
    <renderer:ExtendedDatePicker x:Name="dateOfBirth"
                                NullableDate="{x:Null}"
                                MaximumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
      <DatePicker.Format>dd.MM.yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
      <DatePicker.MinimumDate>
        <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
          <x:Arguments>
            <x:String>Jan 1 0001</x:String>
          </x:Arguments>
        </sys:DateTime>
      </DatePicker.MinimumDate>
    </renderer:ExtendedDatePicker>

    <Button x:Name="clearButton"
            Text="Reset"
            Clicked="OnClearButtonClicked" />
    <Button x:Name="showButton"
            Text="Show values"
            Clicked="OnShowButtonClicked" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnShowButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Date: " + this.dateOfBirth.Date);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NullableDate: " + this.dateOfBirth.NullableDate);

        return;
    }

    private void OnClearButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dateOfBirth.NullableDate = null;
    }
}
```

*ExtendedDatePicker.cs*

```cs
public class ExtendedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("NullableDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (value != NullableDate)
            {
                SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value);
                UpdateDate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        UpdateDate();
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == DateProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (Date != default(DateTime))
            {
                NullableDate = Date;
            }
            else
            {
                NullableDate = null;
            }
        }

        if (propertyName == NullableDateProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (NullableDate.HasValue && Date != NullableDate.Value)
            {
                Date = NullableDate.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDate()
    {
        if (NullableDate.HasValue)
        {
            Date = NullableDate.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            Date = (DateTime)DateProperty.DefaultValue;
            //Date = default(DateTime);
        }
    }
}
```

*ExtendedDatePickerRenderer.cs*

```cs
public class ExtendedDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = Element as ExtendedDatePicker;

        if (e.OldElement != null || view == null)
            return;

        var calendarDatePicker = new CalendarDatePicker();
        calendarDatePicker.DateChanged += CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged;
        SetNativeControl(calendarDatePicker);

        SetNullableText(view);
    }

    private void CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged(CalendarDatePicker sender, CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var view = this.Element as ExtendedDatePicker;
        if (args.NewDate.HasValue)
        {
            DateTime newDate = args.NewDate.GetValueOrDefault().LocalDateTime.Date;
            view.NullableDate = newDate;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var view = (ExtendedDatePicker)Element;

        if (e.PropertyName == ExtendedDatePicker.NullableDateProperty.PropertyName)
            SetNullableText(view);
    }

    private void SetNullableText(ExtendedDatePicker view)
    {
        if (view.NullableDate == null)
            Control.Date = null;
    }
}
```

What do I have to change that `Date` has the same value as `NullableDate`? And the value should represent the value selected in the `DatePicker`. There should also be the possibility to reset to a default value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. It seems to work for me

Comment: Have you used the `showButton` to print out the values? One test case: 1. print 2. reset 3. print 4. set calendar date picker 5. print 6. `clearButton` 7. print. I got it managed that I can work with the `NullableDate`, but why is `Date` wrong? How did you test that? On device or on Windows machine? Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: I am testing on Windows 10 Local Machine. I put breakpoint in UpdateDate of ExtendedDatePicker and I get calls from renderer with NullableDate having right values. OnShowButton_Clicked also shows right values. I would use DateSelected event instead of many properties you are using including DateSelected in renderer.  The only problem I see is in Reset when the value is correct but UI shows old date or not selected but I don't see all the time default value

Comment: Interesting observation. I f I don't use custom renderer everything works as expected, so it is something in renderer's code

Comment: Side question. if you are suing custom control on each platform why you need to derive your ExtendedDatePicker from DatePicker at all?

Comment: I only use a custom control on UWP. For iOS/Android I use the XF associated `DatePicker` control. Most of the time the `Date` property has an old date (selected before) or current days date in it. Which Win10 version do you have exactly? I don't have the anniversary update yet. Which `DateSelected` event do you mean?

Comment: I think I got what the problem is. You are using in renderer native control while there is another control in Forms which derived from DatePicker. So now you have 2 sets of properties which need to be in sync. I wouldn't derive ExtendedDatePicker from DatePicker and just made it as View. Then you need to deal only with 1 set in your renderer. If you need more help with this let me know. If you want to stick with your design then don't forget to update Control.Date in your renderer

Comment: You will have to rethink how you do that. In UpdateDate Date = NullableDate.Value;doesn't work. After you step over this line the Date is not getting assigned.

Comment: Yeah the issue lies in the complexity in syncing of the two controls as well as the two properties `Date` and `SelectedDate`. If I derive from `View` I would need to re-implement all properties of `DatePicker`, while using the correct native `DatePicker` implementation. Seems to be a voluntary extra task to reimplement a whole XF control and add some additional properties to it. It would be nice if there would be an easier way, but yeah. Currently, I got it managed to achieve, that `NullableDate` is in sync and I can work with it for now (though not ideal).